# Get element by class name via browser C#

Tags: c#, html

I have:

```
<h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline">
<a href="http://www.printesaurbana.ro/2015/10/idei-despre-un-start-bun-in-blogging.html" Idei despre un start bun în blogging </a>
</h2>
```

I want get href using class name, I try:

```
if (webBrowser1.Document != null)
                {
                    var links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");

                    foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
                    {
                        if (link.GetAttribute("class") == "entry-title")
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Here");

                        }
                    }
                }
```

But didn't work. How solve this?

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `link.GetAtribute("className")`. Besides, it is the `h2` tag in your html document that has the `entry-title` class. Corrected code:

```
if (webBrowser1.Document != null)
            {
                var links = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("h2");

                foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
                {
                    if (link.GetAttribute("className") == "entry-title")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Here");

                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: in your html document, you don't even have a `link` with a class "entry-title". It is the `h2` tag which has the class "entry-title". So you should use `GetElementsByTagName("h2");`. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. Now works, how I can show href link in MesageboxShow?

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(link.GetAttribute("href"));`

Comment: Didn't work, I try `MessageBox.Show(link.GetAttribute("href"));`

Comment: The name href does not exist

Comment: Oh, this time you are trying to get `href` from `link` which is a `h2` element, remember? So, you have to use `MessageBox.Show(link.Children[0].GetAttribute("href"));`

Comment: Thanks. This helped me a lot. Thanks again.

Comment: if it helped, you may consider accepting this answer and upvoting it.